# PHP Decorator Debugging

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, decorator

Reading [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns/) and worked through the Decorator example. The code is returning `<strong></strong>` instead of the expected `<strong><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></strong>`.

```
class HtmlLinks {
//some methods which is available to all html links
}

class LogoutLink extends HtmlLinks 
{
protected $_html;

public function __construct() {
$this->_html = "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";
}

public function setHtml($html) {
$this->_html = $html;
}

public function render() {
    echo $this->_html;
}
}


class LogoutLinkStrongDecorator extends HtmlLinks {
   protected $_logout_link;

    public function __construct( $logout_link ) {
    $this->_logout_link = $logout_link;
    $this->setHtml("<strong>" . $this->_html . "</strong>");
    }

    public function __call( $name, $args ) {
    $this->_logout_link->$name($args[0]);
    }
}

$logout_link = new LogoutLink();

$logout_link = new LogoutLinkStrongDecorator($logout_link);
$logout_link->render();
```

Tried to debug all afternoon but I haven't made any headway. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to pull the _html from the inner object. You need to add it to each constructor method  of each decorator. Basically add this $this->_html=$_linked_obj->_html.

Comment: This is the part I've been trying to solve. I've been trying to do this in the LogoutLinkStrongDecorator __construct method (adding `$this->_html = $logout_link->_html` or `$this->_html = $this->_logout_link->_html`). But everything I've tried leads to an error like `Cannot access protected property LogoutLink::$_html`

Comment: change  the var to a static variable. You can also delete extends... I  also think the most common way  is to use an interface.

Comment: Any visibility keyword works once I removed the leading underscores from the variable declarations. Changed `$this->setHtml("<strong>" . $this->_html . "</strong>");` to `$this->setHtml("<strong>" . $this->_logout_link->_html . "</strong>");`

Answer (score 0):

Decorator pattern:

1. The Decorator and the Decorated Object implement the same interface.
2. The Decorator takes an object implementing the shared interface in its constructor.

You don't **necessarily** want your decorator to inherit from the class it decorates. You just care that it implements the method you need in the context you're using it (in this case, "render()"), which you can enforce by using Interfaces. The benefit of using inheritance is that all other methods are guaranteed to still be callable, and you'll also get back an instance of the class you passed in.

The code:

```
interface Renderable
{
    public function render();
}

class HtmlLink implements Renderable
{
    public function render()
    {
        return '<a href="'.$this->href.'">'.$this->anchorText.'</a>';
    }
    // other link methods...
}

class StrongRenderableDecorator implements Renderable
{
    protected $renderable;
    public function __construct(Renderable $renderable)
    {
        $this->renderable = $renderable;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return '<strong>'.$this->renderable->render().'</strong>';
    }
}

$logout_link = new StrongRenderableDecorator(new LogoutLink());
$logout_link->render();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This isn't production code, it's pseudocode - there's a clear reference to two properties (anchorText and href) that aren't defined. The point is that the Decorator pattern works by implementing a shared interface, not by inheriting from the same class.

Comment: What do you mean  production  code? I wrote a decorator long ago.

Comment: To be clear I agree with you its only  the code of the tutorial works when the small error is fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see that you were referencing Nettuts/Wikipedia. I added clarification to my response regarding the tradeoff. I learned Decorator from the Head First book, where it's stressed throughout that one should program to an abstraction / interface.